# "Nested independence" of $\mathsf{ZFC}$?

Tags: set-theory

I have a question about undecidable statements in $\mathsf{ZFC}$.

I know there are true statements like:
$$X\text{ is independent of }\mathsf{ZFC}.$$

But is it also possible that such a statement exists?

$$\text{"}X\text{ is independent of }\mathsf{ZFC}\text{" is independent of }\mathsf{ZFC}$$

Or even worse:

$$\text{""}X\text{ is independent of }\mathsf{ZFC}\text{" is independent of }\mathsf{ZFC}\text{" is independent of }\mathsf{ZFC}$$

I think you see what I mean by "nested independence of $\mathsf{ZFC}$". Is it possible that such a true statement exists? If it is possible: What does it mean? And is there an example for such a true statement? Unless such a true statement can exist: Why not?

Another funny case would be is the depth of this nested statement goes to infinity:

$$\begin {align}
\mathrm{statement}_0 &= X \\
\mathrm{statement}_{n+1} &= \mathrm{statement}_n\text{ is independent of }\mathsf{ZFC} \\
\mathrm{specialstatement} &= \lim_{n\to\infty}\mathrm{statement}_n
\end{align}$$

Does such a $\mathrm{specialstatement}$ exist? And what is the meaning of it?

Comment: thx for the link:)

Comment: Milo's answer to the 'duplicate' question is wrong because it does not deal with provability correctly. Specifically, you need to state provability **over what theory**. Independence likewise. Also, ZFC **cannot** even prove that any one sentence is independent of ZFC, otherwise ZFC is inconsistent! Thus your initial statement is already wrong, unless your meta-system is stronger than ZFC, in which case your question is not well-defined because you didn't specify what exactly your meta-system is.